# xarray: dynamically select function for array reduction

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-xarray

What is the best way to wrap array reduction functions such as `xarray.DataArray.mean` into a function / method to allow for a dynamic selection of the reduction function?

The way I've come up is basically passing a function to `xarray.DataArray.reduce`:

```py
class AwesomeClass:
    def __init__(self, xarray_obj):
        self._obj = xarray_obj
        
    def _reduce_by_10(self, fun, dim):
        """Reduce by steps of 10 over dim"""
        
        obj = self._obj
        """
        bunch of stuff happening here to obj
        that's the same independent of the reduction
        function
        """
        for index in range(0, x[dim].size, 10):
            region = {dim: slice(index, index+10)}
            yield obj.isel(region).reduce(fun, dim=dim)
    
    def mean(self, dim="time"):
        yield from self._reduce_by_10(np.mean, dim=dim)
    
    def sum(self, dim="time"):
        yield from self._reduce_by_10(np.sum, dim=dim)


# sample data if needed
arr = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.RandomState(0).randn(2, 3), [("x", ["a", "b"]), ("y", [10, 20, 30])]
)
```

**Edit:**

Instead of passing the reduction function to `_reduce_by_10` I could also yield the sliced `obj` back to the respective method and then use the existing `.mean`/`.sum` functions of `xarray.DataArray`:

```py
class AwesomeClass:
    def __init__(self, xarray_obj):
        self._obj = xarray_obj
        
    def _slice_by_10(self, dim):
        """Reduce by steps of 10 over dim"""
        
        obj = self._obj
        """
        bunch of stuff happening here to obj
        that's the same independent of the reduction
        function
        """
        for index in range(0, x[dim].size, 10):
            region = {dim: slice(index, index+10)}
            yield obj.isel(region)
    
    def mean(self, dim="time"):
        for obj in self._slice_by_10(dim):
            yield obj.mean(dim)
    
    def sum(self, dim="time"):
        for obj in self._slice_by_10(dim):
            yield obj.sum(dim)
```

To re-phrase my questions:

- Is using `obj.reduce(np.mean, dim)` equivalent to `obj.mean(dim)`?
- Is there a preferable way between the two above? I'm not sure about the "double `yield`", I thought `yield from` is nicer.

Comment: `.reduce` is very reasonable. `xr.apply_ufunc` has some more bells & whistles. Ofc for mean / sum, the existing `.mean` & `.sum` functions on a `DataArray` work well.

Comment: Thanks @Maximilian - I'd like to use `.mean` or `.sum` - but I need a way to call them dynamically (not sure if that was clear). So its using `.reduce` the best way to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean "dynamically"? In the example we have a sum method calling reduce with Nanaimo. Instead, it can call xarray's sum directly.

Comment: Sorry if not clear @Maximilian - I've edited my example, hopefully it's clearer now (also removed the `nan` methods to keep it consistent). I guess what it boils down is if `obj.reduce(np.mean, dim)` is the same as `obj.mean(dim)`.

Comment: It looks reasonable! To the extent we can get the result with a groupby rather than iterating over the slices, that's more idiomatic. But looks decent.

Comment: Thanks! I tend to stay away from groupby, rolling etc. because I had issues scaling this to big objects and dask. Thanks for your input, much appreciated. If you'd like, you can submit an answer with a few key points for me to accept